# Plot high-low with Seaborn, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that has by category three data points: mean, max, min.

I'd like to plot these such that the mean is a dot and the max/min are a line.  Similar to a high/low/close graph in stocks, or even just error bars.

For the sake of conversation, assume my code looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['M', 'T', 'W', 'F'],
              'foo' : [1,2,3,4],
              'foo_max' : [5,5,6,7],
              'foo_min' : [0,1,1,1]})

sns.stripplot(df.day, df.foo, color='black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: use high/low//open/close and modified data, remove the extra datapoints.

Comment: Not sure I follow @Merlin , what would the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
df.set_index('day', inplace=True)

# tsplot with error bars
ax = sns.tsplot([df['foo_max'], df['foo_min']], err_style="ci_bars", 
                interpolate=False, color='g')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, df.shape[0]))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index) 
ax.set_ylim(0, df.values.max()+1)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]